# How to install new software menu component

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I want to create a component in Eclipse like this:

[image]

i see this is a `Jtable` but i want this kind of drop down panel like in the picture.

Can you give me some advice what kind of component is it?

Comment: you can use JTree follow the below links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847411/java-swing-need-a-good-quality-developed-jtree-with-checkboxes

Comment: This is betweeen JTree and JTable but i need JTable features. In my program this panel will be used the same way like in eclipse.

Comment: Note that Eclipse uses SWT not Swing for its own UI code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse uses the SWT and JFace UI toolkits rather than Swing.

The 'Work with' component is an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo` with Read/Write style.

The tree list viewer is an `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer`