# How to make new tree which contains subtree from JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Basically I need help with recursion. The point is that I am trying to make dialog which shows JTree with check boxes and I did it (copying most popular code here). But I can only copy whole tree from main frame, and what I need is selected component to be root of a new tree. So I guess I have to build new DefaultTreeModel for a new tree.

I tried every example I found ... from here to everywhere. I saw that people use recursion, but I can't apply codes that are given in right way or they just don't fit.

[So this is my dialog class where I make new tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3LzP.png)

[It works when I try to check whole tree copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br8yA.png)

[But when I try to check copied subtree this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvQbA.png)

[This is the line with NullPointerException, somehow nodesCheckingState.get(tp) returns null, nodeCheckingState is hash map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czFjX.png)

I pasted whole code from here [Java Swing: Need a good quality developed JTree with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847411/java-swing-need-a-good-quality-developed-jtree-with-checkboxes)

Comment: Add the code you've tried and specifically where you're having an issue.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer did it

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it! All I needed to do is to set parent of new root to null. :)**